# calculating weekly avg time based on category

Tags: sql, time, calendar, average, categories

I have a table which shows ticket details that were closed between given dates. With these columns:

```
Category,
ticket_Number, 
RequestOpenDate, 
RequestClosedDate,
time_take_In_hours
```

Each ticket comes under a particular category. Based on the category I want to generate weekly avg time taken to close the ticket.

Example: for the given dates *'01-01-2017'* and *'01-04-2017'* I expect this output:

```
**Category**    **Weekly_Avg_In_Hours**
Category1               122
Category2               100
Category3                89
```

I tried many ways and finally managed to get below output:

```
**Month**   **Category**    **Week**    **Avg_Time_In_Hours**
January       Category1       Week1       100
January       Category2       Week1        90
January       Category3       Week1        80
January       Category1       Week2        90
January       Category2       Week2        80
January       Category3       Week2       100
February      Category1       Week1        80
February      Category2       Week1        50
February      Category3       Week1       100
February      Category1       Week2        90
February      Category2       Week2        76
February      Category3       Week2       100
```

Another problem is the week count.
I want to consider 2017 july 1st as week 1 and july 2nd to 8 as week 2 ... july 30 and 31 as week 6:

[image]

Comment: You forgot to provide the database system and version in use and the query you have (even if it's not working as desired).

Comment: I am using (RDBMS)Microsoft SQL server 2014 and regarding the output, the result  is totally wrong,i am getting ticket count instead of avg time in 'Avg_Time_In_Hours' column..